# Google Maps Distance Matrix Service API returning wrong items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to sort items in React.js based on their distance from a user inputted location. The following code sets up the API call.

```
autofill = (event) => {
    var dest = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    var origins = [];

    this.props.items.forEach(function(element) {
        origins.push(element.latLong);
    });

    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: origins,
        destinations: [dest],
        travelMode: 'WALKING'}, this.callback);
}
```

Earlier in the application, the items stored in this.props.items can be filtered. Imagine there are three items, `[1,2,3]`. I filter out 1, meaning that `this.props.items` is now equal to `[2,3]`. I have verified this by printing `origin` to the console after the forEach loop.

Inside `callback()`, the request callback function, I print out the response and the `originAddresses` list returned by the API holds addresses corresponding to `[1,3]`! How is this possible, since I only passed the API `2` and `3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Turns out I had certain coordinates the wrong way round so this is not actually an issue. Oops.